# Writing to a GL_R8 texture

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, shader, render-to-texture

I am having some trouble writing to a texture (GL_R8 Format) attached to an FBO while reading from another texture attached to the same FBO (GL_RGB32F). I believe the problem is with the output type in my fragment shader.

Texture Initialization:

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &rBuffer->fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, rBuffer->fbo);


    glGenTextures(RayBuffer_TextureType_NUMTEXTURES, rBuffer->textures);
    ...
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rBuffer->textures[RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW]);
    glTexImage2D
    (
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,  
            0,         
            GL_R8,        
            textureWidth,
            textureHeight,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            NULL
    );

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glFramebufferTexture2D
    (
            GL_FRAMEBUFFER,                                
            GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW,
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            rBuffer->textures[RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW],
            0
    );
```

Binding:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, rBuffer->fbo);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_POSITION);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rBuffer->textures[RayBuffer_TextureType_POSITION]);
```

Geometry Shader:

```
#version 330
layout(triangles) in; 
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=4) out;
uniform sampler2D positionTexture;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;
uniform vec3 rightDirection;
uniform vec3 upDirection;
uniform vec2 screenSize;
void main()
{



    gl_Position = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 3) out float out_shadow;
void main()
{
    out_shadow = 1.0f;
}
```

Blitting the texture to the screen:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, members->rBuffer->fbo);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW);
    glBlitFramebuffer
    (
            0, 0, eBuffer->windowWidth, eBuffer->windowHeight,
            0, 0, eBuffer->windowWidth, eBuffer->windowHeight,
            GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR
    );
```

It is safe to assume that RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW is 3. Furthermore, it should be noted I have stripped out all complexities of the geometry shader to try and find the origin of the problem. The code produces a completely black screen while I was expecting a completely red screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the way you bind your output buffer. The critical line is here:

```
layout (location = 3) out float out_shadow;
```

You seem to assume that the value 3 is needed to match the index of the color attachment of the FBO you render to:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D
(
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER,                                
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW,
```

with a value of 3 for `RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW`.

This is not how the association of fragment shader output to FBO attachment works. The value you specify with the `layout(location=...)` qualifier is called the **color number** in most parts of the spec. For example on page 190 of the OpenGL 3.3 spec, while describing `glBindFragDataLocationIndexed()`, it talks about:

> The binding of a user-deﬁned varying out variable to a fragment color number [..]

and on the next page (emphasis added by me):

> When a program is linked, any varying out variables without a binding specified either through BindFragDataLocationIndexed or BindFragDataLocation, **or explicitly set within the shader text** will automatically be bound to **fragment colors** and indices by the GL.

Now, these "color numbers" match up with the index of the draw buffers you specified. From the description of `glDrawBuffer()` on page 210 of the same document:

> deﬁnes the set of color buffers to which fragment **color zero** is written.

So with your call:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + RayBuffer_TextureType_SHADOW);
```

you specify that color **0** produced by the fragment shader is written to attachment **3** of your FBO.

What this all means is that you need to specify color number **0** for the output of the fragment shader:

```
layout (location = 0) out float out_shadow;
```

Color numbers larger than 0 are only useful if you produce more than one output from your fragment shader. In that case, the `location` values specify the index of the color buffer within the list passed to `glDrawBuffers()` that the output is written to.

Comment: Oh my goodness, what a misunderstanding on my part. Thank you for clarifying that. That makes a lot of sense. I will update my code and come back with the results.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, but more importantly I now correctly understand how rendering to textures works. Thank you again. I noticed that the title of the question doesn't really represent the fundamental mistake I had made here. Does anybody think it should be changed to something else (and what would be suggested)?